# Is it possible for a token to have 2 or more owners?

Tags: solidity

is it possible to transfer ownership to another address ?
Can a token have 2 adrress as owner apart from multisig wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are asking for really.

`Owner` can be treated as a holder of a token OR the `Owner` of the smart contract.

If we just talk about holders:

- `ERC20` tokens can have multiple holders
- `ERC721` token can have one holder per unique ID
- `ERC1155` token can have multiple holders

If we talk about the ownership of the smart contract, then you probably refer to [OpenZeppelin's Access Control](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/access-control). That only supports one owner. You could amend that to support more than one though.